# Dataiku Failed to Create the Tutorial

Tags: data-science-studio

I am new to Dataiku and was going through the tutorials. When I tried to create the `Automation (Tutorial)` I receive the following error code:

```
Failed to create the tutorial.
Tutorial project import failed: {"usedProjectKey":"DKU_TUTORIAL_AUTOMATION","neededAMigration":true,"usedConnections"
:[],"messages":[{"severity":"ERROR","code":"ERR_BUNDLE_ACTIVATE_MISSING_CONNECTION","title":"Missing connection",
"details":"Connection missing for folder Orders (not remapped): filesystem_folders (Filesystem)",
"message":"Missing connection: Connection missing for folder Orders (not remapped): filesystem_folders (Filesystem)"},
{"severity":"ERROR","code":"ERR_BUNDLE_ACTIVATE_MISSING_CONNECTION","title":"Missing connection",
"details":"Connection missing for folder Customers (not remapped): filesystem_folders (Filesystem)",
"message":"Missing connection: Connection missing for 
folder Customers (not remapped): filesystem_folders (Filesystem)"}],
"maxSeverity":"ERROR","anyMessage":true,"success":false,"warning":false,"error":true}
```

I troubleshot with the Q&A found  [here](https://community.dataiku.com/t5/Using-Dataiku-DSS/fail-to-create-automation-tutorial-project/td-p/3043) but unfortunately I am still receiving the above error. I did not have the latter issue that the user in the previous thread had mentioned. Any help is very much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options:

1) Check the log file from the DSS datadir (for example /PATH-TO-YOUR-DSS-FOLDER/ run/ log)

2) Reach out to the iku admin if you're unable to debug the issue.

They are usually responsive & get things sorted asap!